# bzr-eclipse 1.4 needs xmloutput >= 0.9.2

Tags: eclipse-plugin, centos, bazaar

I'm trying to install Eclipse Kepler (4.3) IDE with Bazaar version control system integration on a CentOS 6.5 machine. Everything seems perfect, until I restart the IDE and want to use bazaar. It asks for xmloutput >= 0.9.2 but according to [this page](https://launchpad.net/bzr-xmloutput) the latest version available is xmloutput 0.8.8

I have tried to install bzr-eclipse 1.3 or 1.2 but all the links in Eclipse are  just for the latest version.

Does anybody know how to install a previous version of bzr-eclipse or how to use a correct version of xmloutput?

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be very close to [this question](https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr-eclipse/+question/243416) (resolved by upgrading to a newer version of Bazaar).